# Log Into Vista Using Keyboard Only

Tags: windows-vista, keyboard, login

Is it possible to log in (with a new session or a locked session) to Windows Vista using only a keyboard? E.g. if I want to log into Windows XP I press CTRL-ALT-DELETE and then start typing in my password.

With Vista I have to use my mouse to click on an icon of my name before I'm permitted to start typing.

I don't want to use the mouse. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Enter/Return</kbd> quite a bit, but it is easily possible!

Comment: Is there a better answer? I could be blindfolded and still log into XP..

Comment: No, and this is a good answer! It is **very** easy to do!

Comment: In XP, you could use the arrows to select a user as well. I don't know if this works in Vista.

Comment: Yes Arrows also work when in a section, but tab goes through everything and I personally find it easier, but +1 as arrows to work!

Comment: Accepted as answer as technically correct; unfortunately not the straight-forward answer I was hoping for. Why did Microsoft deliberately make Vista far more difficult to use!